# c++ passing element of vector<Parent*> into object's method requiring chidren

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector

In C++, I have `Parent` class. `Child1`, `Child2`, etc. inherit from it. Classes `Child1`, `Child2`, etc. share some methods of the parent and have their own methods.

I declare a `vector` to be able to add any child of `Parent`.

```
vector<Parent*> v = {new Child1(), new Child2(),...};
```

Depending on a child, I want to define different behaviour for a method of `BClass::someMethod(Child1* child)`, `BClass::someMethod(Child2* child)`... Something like **Visitor pattern**. The problem is that I must pass an element of `v` vector into `BClass::someMethod(...)` and the compiler says, for example for method `BClass::someMethod(Child1* c1)` when `v[0]` is passed:

```
Argument of type Parent* is incompatible with parameter of type Child1*
```

Could you please tell me how to overcome the issue?

Comment: You'll need to use `dynamic_cast<Child1*>(v[0])`. But needing to do so is usually a sign of overall bad design. Better define reasonable interfaces (pure virtual abstract classes). Also remember please: You'll have to provide a [mcve] reproducing your problem in your question (shouldn't be hard to setup in your case).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I could give the code, the problem is that it's really a lot!

Comment: That's why it says ***minimal***. I don't believe that it's very hard to put into a small example program what you've been explaining in prose. You can use a [online compiler](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com) to do that quickly.

Comment: Also I'd recommend to read about the [_Visitor Design Pattern_](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor) again.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I'll do :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OOP solution is to add a virtual member function to `Parent`, implement the *different behaviour* in overridden member functions of children, and change the argument of `BClass::someMethod` to a `Parent` pointer (or reference), and call the virtual function in there - or get rid of `BClass::someMethod` entirely, and use the virtual function directly in case `BClass::someMethod` no longer has other functionality.

---

P.S. Storing dynamic allocations in bare pointers is not a good design. Smart pointers are recommended instead.